# Is there any trick to make Visual Studio Code Quick Open faster?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quick Open is a must-have feature in any IDE, but in Visual Studio Code (by default bound to cmd+e on Mac) it seems to be very slow in finding anything. Is there any configuration option/trick to make it faster by indexing files etc.?

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55) the relevant issue on VS Code Github repo to track progress on this topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We plan to add indexing in future updates. Until then you can configure to exclude more folders from searches. The setting is called `search.exclude` and allows to set patterns.

Btw quick open learns about files you open often and keeps those in a MRU list. Quick open should be fast for those files.

Comment: Thanks, just excluding Library and build folders in large Unity projects seems to help quite a bit.

Comment: Can't wait for the indexing feature to land - it will make me much happier in vscode.

Comment: Also - is there an issue on github or something that we can star for this? I'd love to know if it's been prioritized. It sometimes takes like 20seconds to do a "quick search" ;0

Comment: The quick open feature seems really slow even given the lack of indexing. Like, I can run `find .` at the terminal and get a complete list of files in a fraction of a second. So why does Visual Studio Code take minutes to find a file with a given name?

Comment: Starting with the release of 1.5, VS Code is in fact also using the find command to populate the results. The only thing on top of that which has impact on speed is sorting and scoring of all the results and sending them over to the UI.

Comment: Apparently indexing was added as noted in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/cc-extension-for-visual-studio-code/) - however I still can't get it to work in Linux - no red flame icons for me...any one else have this working in linux? (c/c++)

Comment: Is it `files.exclude` or `search.exclude` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613874/902102. I am confused in both of them

Comment: Got it by looking into settings.json. `files.exclude` is to exclude files & folder from displaying in sidebar and `search.exclude` is to exclude from indexing for search.

Answer (score 2):

This extension might be useful for opening files faster:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/astral-keks.folder-indexing

It allows user to navigate to any file in workspace by just typing part of its name in editbox opened by `workbench.action.showAllSymbols (Go To Symbol In Workspace)` command.