# How to see list of project files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a vscode project that I know has too many files in it.  When I do searches the system is grinding away to search through many many files and I get the little warning in the status bar once in a while suggesting to add files to files.exclude.  The problem is, I don't know where the extra files are coming from.  My guess is that somewhere I have overlooked some temp files or data directories, but I can't find them in the folder view.  (I am sure they are there, but manually searching I don't see them)

So my question is, does vscode have a way to see a list or ask for a list of all files that are considered part of the project so I can track down where the ones I don't need are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that would slow your search down are:

1. Unnecessarily tracked folders with lots of files in them (`dist`, `vendor`, etc...)
2. Huge files

For #1, you could do a generic search and see if weird folders are showing up in the search results.  Add them to `files.exclude` in settings and then re-search.

For #2, open up the embedded terminal and run the command `find ./ -size +5000 -print`.  This will find all files > 5Mb.  For anything that doesn't need to be searched, add the file (or whole folder) to the blocklist.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613250/1169948.

Comment: Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab