# VS code quick search in all files all code instantaneously

Tags: visual-studio-code

Current palette # search only finds tags/variables in the current opened files, but in webstorm **searches for a text in all code/files in your project as you type instantaneously, regardless of being a tag or variable**, is there a tool/addon that does this in VS code? current search (Ctrl+shift+f) you have to press Enter and takes a while to get all the results.

Here is an example from webstorm
[image: webstorm]

Comment: Can you provide more info about the expected behavior? The screenshot just looks like the file quick open in the command palette: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette

Comment: To be able to search like the command palette does for symbols in the current opened file, but also for any kind of text inside the files regardless of being open or not.

Comment: Try symbol search: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name It requires language support but may be what you are after

Comment: Thanks matt, pretty close, problem is symbol only searches on the current opened file and only searches for variables, tags, I want a instant text quick search on all file names, file content like webstorm does in the screenshot.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957600/836330 There is a new quick search for text in workspace files that you may find useful.

Answer (score 2):

To get both files and symbols in quick open, try setting:

```
"search.quickOpen.includeSymbols": true
```

The symbol search results require language support. VS Code ships with support for JavaScript and TypeScript symbol search, but you'll need an extension to getting symbols for languages like php.

If an extension is only returning symbols for open documents instead of all documents in the workspace, please file an issue against them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Quick Search command of [this extension](https://github.com/wmedrano/wmedrano_vscode_extension). As of VSCode 1.55, it still works (you'll have to install [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) though).

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you can use `CMD+P` to get a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code 1.85 added "Quick Search" as an experimental feature. It gives an interface similar to Quick Open (which searches file names instead of file contents). You can use Quick Search in 1.85 via the `Search: Quick Text Search (Experimental)` command in 1.85. The command name will probably change in 1.86 to something that doesn't have "(Experimental)" in it. Its command ID in 1.85 is `workbench.action.experimental.quickTextSearch`.

Note that searching symbols in all files actually sounds like what you're asking for- just that whatever extension is providing language support for the language you're writing in doesn't register what you want to find as a "symbol". The command for searching symbols in all files is `Go to Symbol in Workspace...`, which you can also access by opening the Quick Open menu and prefixing your search with a `#` character. Or you can make Quick Open include symbols automatically by using the `search.quickOpen.includeSymbols` setting.